# Sed replace with regex

Tags: regex, file-io, sed

I can't get a simple regex replacement to work with sed. Here is the example I'm faced with.

I am trying to replace lines in a file, from this:

```
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=274
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=275
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=276
select * from othertable where othertable.id=?
select * from table3 where table3.name=?
```

to this:

```
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=?
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=?
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=?
select * from othertable where othertable.id=?
select * from table3 where table3.name=?
```

I am using sed as such for now:

```
cat log | sed 's/where mytable\.s_id=[0-9]+/where mytable.s_id=/g' | sort
```

But the regex I am using in sed (`'s/where mytable\.s_id=[0-9]+/where mytable.s_id=/g'`) doesn't replace anything.

I am reading as much documentation as I can, but everything I read is different, with different way of doing things so I am a little lost. What is the canonical way for a regex replacement using sed, and what would it look like in my particuliar case?

*Note*: I simplified the problem I'm facing. I *do* want to use sed (to finally learn to use it) and I *do* want to pipe the input and output (not editing the file in place) because the command line I use is actually more complicated than that.

Comment: Is there a space between .s and id, or an underscore?

Comment: You seem to be using GNU sed where `+` is supported. You either need to escape it by prepending `\ ` or run `sed` with the extended regular expression switch `-r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat log | sed 's/where mytable\.s_id=[0-9]\+/where mytable.s_id=?/g'
```

Just a backslash before the +.

Comment: Thanks! Why does it need escaping? I find it weird to have to escape a special character, whereas I don't need to escape `[0-9]`. Do I need also to escape `*` for example?

Comment: Yes you need to escape some special characters as . + and *   In fact these characters are interpreted as specification for the regular expression. If you want to learn more of this, try to get a tutorial on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Quote the `+`:

```
sed 's/where mytable\.s_id=[0-9]\+/where mytable.s_id=?/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, some sed don't know about the `+`. Hence, try this:

```
 cat log | sed 's/where mytable\.s_id=[0-9]*/where mytable.s_id=?/g' | sort
```

EDIT: the `+` is a GNU-extension and if you use it (and your sed knows it) you must escape it, like choroba suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are interested in awk

```
awk -F= '{$2="=?";print}' temp
```

tested below;

```
> cat temp
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=275
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id=276
select * from othertable where othertable.id=?
select * from table3 where table3.name=?
> awk -F= '{$2="=?";print}' temp
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id =?
select * from mytable where mytable.s_id =?
select * from othertable where othertable.id =?
select * from table3 where table3.name =?
```

Comment: I want to use sed, I emphasized on that in my question